# Reference to a hash with struct class

Tags: perl

Hello I'm tryting to reference a hash array with a structure, but doesn't work when I need to write on it.

```
use warnings;
use Class::Struct;

struct lib  => {
    content   =>    '$',
    type       =>   '$',
};

my %library ;

$library{"one"} = lib->new();
$library{"one"}->content("first text here \n");
my $ref = \$library{"one"}->content();
print $$ref ;
$$ref = "Second text\n" ;
print $$ref ;
print $library{"one"}->content() ;
```

How can I make the reference to update the content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the content of the structure, just use the appropriate method:

```
$library{one}->content("Second text\n");
```

If you really want to break encapsulation, you can try

```
my $ref = \$library{one}{'lib::content'};
$$ref = "Second text\n";
print $$ref;
print $library{one}->content;
```